# How to resolve these cpp errors?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

USING VISUAL STUDIO 2019

Errors I receive are:

E0065 - Line 104

E0112 - Line 133

C2601 - Line 134

C2601 - Line 146

I have tried rearranging the segments of code, removing or altering others, and have exhausted the options I could think of. Not really sure what went wrong and any help is appreciated. I can provide screenshots of the directions I followed as well if needed.

```
// bring in libraries

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> // read/write to files
#include <ctime> // time(0)
#include <iomanip> // setprecision( )
using namespace std;
    
    // prototypes
    void deposit(double* ptrBalance);
    void withdrawal(double* ptrBalance, float dailyLimit); // overloaded method this version does not take withdrawal amount
    void withdrawal(double* ptrBalance, float dailyLimit, float amount); // overloaded method that takes withdrawal amount

/// Entry point to the application
int main()
{

    // Create constant variables
    const int EXIT_VALUE = 5;
    const float DAILY_LIMIT = 400.0f;
    const string FILENAME = "Account.txt";


    // create loop variable BEFORE the loop
    short choice = 0;

    // Create balance variable
    double balance = 0.0;

    // Look for the starting balance; otherwise generate a random starting balance
    ifstream iFile(FILENAME.c_str());
    if(iFile.is_open())
    {
        // Did the file open? If so, read the balance.
        iFile >> balance;
        iFile.close();
    }
    else
    {

        // If the file did not open or does not exist, create a random number for the starting balance
        srand(time(0));
        const int MIN = 1000;
        const int MAX = 10000;
        balance = rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN;
    }

    std::cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "Starting Balance: $" << balance << endl;

    // Let's create a pointer and set it to the balance variable location
    double* ptrBalance = &balance; // & means "address of"

        // start the application loop
    do
    {

        // show the menu
        system("cls"); // clears the console screen -- for MAC, use system("clear");
        std::cout << "Menu\n" << endl;
        std::cout << "1) Deposit " << endl;
        std::cout << "2) Withdrawal" << endl;
        std::cout << "3) Check Balance" << endl;
        std::cout << "4) Quick $40" << endl;
        std::cout << "5) Exit" << endl;

        // get user input
        std::cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        // run code based on user input
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            deposit(ptrBalance); // Passing a pointer so only 4 bytes have to cross the system bus
            break;
        case 2:
            withdrawal(ptrBalance, DAILY_LIMIT);
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "Showing current balance..." << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "Getting quick $40..." << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            std::cout << "\nGoodbye" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "\nError. Please select from the menu." << endl;
            break;
        }


        /// Make a deposit
        void deposit(double* ptrBalance)
        {
            // get deposit and validate it
            float deposit = 0.0f;

            do
            {
                std::cout << "\nEnter deposit amount";
                cin >> deposit;

                if (cin.fail()) // did they give us a character instead of a number?
                {
                    cin.clear(); // clears fail state
                    cin.ignore(INT16_MAX, '\n'); // clears keyboard buffer
                    std::cout << "\nError. Please input numbers only.\n" << endl;
                    deposit = -1; // set deposit to a "bad" number
                    continue; // restart the loop
                }
                else if (deposit < 0.0f) // check for negative number
                    std::cout << "\nError. Invalid deposit amount.\n" << endl;
            } while (deposit < 0.0f);

            // How do we get the double value located at the pointer?
            // Dereference it using an asterisk
            *ptrBalance += deposit; // same as: *ptrBalance = ptrBalance + deposit;

            std::cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "\nCurrent ptrBalance: $" << *ptrBalance << endl; // notice asterisk
        }

        /// Make a withdrawal
        void withdrawal(double* ptrBalance, float dailyLimit)
        {
            // get the withdrawal (you should validate this input
            float amount = 0.0f;
            std::cout << "\nEnter withdrawal amount: ";
            cin >> amount;

            // call the overloaded method version that takes the balance, dailyLimit, and withdrawal amount
            withdrawal(ptrBalance, dailyLimit, amount);
        }

        /// Make a withdrawal - this overload accepts balance, dailyLimit, and withdrawal amount
        void withdrawal(double* ptrBalance, float dailyLimit, float amount)
        {
            // take money away from account and show the balance
            if (amount > dailyLimit)
            {
                cout << "\nError. Amount exceeds daily limit." << endl;
            }
            else if (amount > * ptrBalance) // notice the asterisk to dereference the pointer!
            {
                cout << "\nError. Insufficient funds." << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                *ptrBalance -= amount; // same as: *ptrBalance = *ptrBalance - amount;
                cout << "\nHere is your cash: $" << amount << endl;
            }
        }
            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "\nCurrent ptrBalance: $" << *ptrBalance << endl;
        

        // pause
        std::cout << "\nPress any key to continue...";
        _getch();
    
    while (choice != EXIT_VALUE);
    return 0;
    // now that the application has ended, write the new balance to the file
    ofstream oFile(FILENAME.c_str());
    oFile << balance << endl;
    oFile.close();

    return 0;
    
    // pause before we clear the screen
    std::cout << "n\Press any key to continue...";
        _getch();

}
```

Comment: You can't nest function definitions in C++, just as C2601 says. So move those outside `main`.

Comment: Creating a [mre] removes noise and red herrings, which helps you focus more specifically on the code that triggers the errors (in addition to the MRE being a requirement for questions asking for debugging help). Compilation errors are typically reproducible with under a dozen lines; seeing an error in "Line 104" indicates that little to no effort was put into simplifying your real code into an example to be used in this question.

Comment: Very few people memorize error codes. Adding the error message would both increase the number of people who could help you with an answer and increase the number of people you can help (the people with similar problems who would find this question after searching for the error message).

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't allow you to define a function inside another function. The only way to do something like that is by using [lambdas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=msvc-160). So when defining a function, don't define it inside another function, define it somewhere else. There were some other errors (and warnings) too which I have corrected and commented out.

```cpp
// bring in libraries

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> // read/write to files
#include <ctime> // time(0)
#include <iomanip> // setprecision( )
using namespace std;

// prototypes   <-- You dont need these.
//void deposit(double* ptrBalance);
//void withdrawal(double* ptrBalance, float dailyLimit); // overloaded method this version does not take withdrawal amount
//void withdrawal(double* ptrBalance, float dailyLimit, float amount); // overloaded method that takes withdrawal amount

/// Make a deposit
void deposit(double* ptrBalance)
{
    // get deposit and validate it
    float deposit = 0.0f;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter deposit amount";
        cin >> deposit;

        if (cin.fail()) // did they give us a character instead of a number?
        {
            cin.clear(); // clears fail state
            cin.ignore(INT16_MAX, '\n'); // clears keyboard buffer
            std::cout << "\nError. Please input numbers only.\n" << endl;
            deposit = -1; // set deposit to a "bad" number
            continue; // restart the loop
        }
        else if (deposit < 0.0f) // check for negative number
            std::cout << "\nError. Invalid deposit amount.\n" << endl;
    } while (deposit < 0.0f);

    // How do we get the double value located at the pointer?
    // Dereference it using an asterisk
    *ptrBalance += deposit; // same as: *ptrBalance = ptrBalance + deposit;

    std::cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "\nCurrent ptrBalance: $" << *ptrBalance << endl; // notice asterisk
}

/// Make a withdrawal - this overload accepts balance, dailyLimit, and withdrawal amount
void withdrawal(double* ptrBalance, float dailyLimit, float amount) // Place this before the other overload as its used by the other one.
{
    // take money away from account and show the balance
    if (amount > dailyLimit)
    {
        cout << "\nError. Amount exceeds daily limit." << endl;
    }
    else if (amount > *ptrBalance) // notice the asterisk to dereference the pointer!
    {
        cout << "\nError. Insufficient funds." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        *ptrBalance -= amount; // same as: *ptrBalance = *ptrBalance - amount;
        cout << "\nHere is your cash: $" << amount << endl;
    }
}

/// Make a withdrawal
void withdrawal(double* ptrBalance, float dailyLimit)
{
    // get the withdrawal (you should validate this input
    float amount = 0.0f;
    std::cout << "\nEnter withdrawal amount: ";
    cin >> amount;

    // call the overloaded method version that takes the balance, dailyLimit, and withdrawal amount
    withdrawal(ptrBalance, dailyLimit, amount);
}

/// Entry point to the application
int main()
{

    // Create constant variables
    const int EXIT_VALUE = 5;
    const float DAILY_LIMIT = 400.0f;
    const string FILENAME = "Account.txt";


    // create loop variable BEFORE the loop
    short choice = 0;

    // Create balance variable
    double balance = 0.0;

    // Look for the starting balance; otherwise generate a random starting balance
    ifstream iFile(FILENAME.c_str());
    if (iFile.is_open())
    {
        // Did the file open? If so, read the balance.
        iFile >> balance;
        iFile.close();
    }
    else
    {

        // If the file did not open or does not exist, create a random number for the starting balance
        srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));  // Cast it to unsigned int.
        const int MIN = 1000;
        const int MAX = 10000;
        balance = static_cast<double>(rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN);
    }

    std::cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "Starting Balance: $" << balance << endl;

    // Let's create a pointer and set it to the balance variable location
    double* ptrBalance = &balance; // & means "address of"

        // start the application loop
    do
    {

        // show the menu
        system("cls"); // clears the console screen -- for MAC, use system("clear");
        std::cout << "Menu\n" << endl;
        std::cout << "1) Deposit " << endl;
        std::cout << "2) Withdrawal" << endl;
        std::cout << "3) Check Balance" << endl;
        std::cout << "4) Quick $40" << endl;
        std::cout << "5) Exit" << endl;

        // get user input
        std::cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        // run code based on user input
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            deposit(ptrBalance); // Passing a pointer so only 4 bytes have to cross the system bus
            break;
        case 2:
            withdrawal(ptrBalance, DAILY_LIMIT);
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "Showing current balance..." << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "Getting quick $40..." << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            std::cout << "\nGoodbye" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "\nError. Please select from the menu." << endl;
            break;
        }


        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "\nCurrent ptrBalance: $" << *ptrBalance << endl;


        // pause
        std::cout << "\nPress any key to continue...";
        _getch();

    } while (choice != EXIT_VALUE);

    //return 0; <-- You cannot have multiple returns.

    // now that the application has ended, write the new balance to the file
    ofstream oFile(FILENAME.c_str());
    oFile << balance << endl;
    oFile.close();

    // pause before we clear the screen
    std::cout << "\nPress any key to continue...";  // It should be \n, not n\
    _getch();

    return 0;   // Place the return at the end.
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I appreciate it. Totally missed those errors

Answer (score 0):

Inside your version of code, you have defined the functions inside `main()`. In `C++`, this thing is not allowed, i.e. definition of one function within another. You can not implement a function within the scope of another function.

Since `main()` is also a function, you are getting a linker error.

Try to define the functions outside the `main()`. Once defined outside, you can call them from `main()`.